# clicked div to load content from server load append result each time clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I have a div "d1" when clicked it load friend request from the server into hidden div d2"",but when i click it multiple time ,it append the same result over and over ,I tried this to help solve the problem

```
if($("#d1").data('clicked')) {              
// do nothing           
    }
else{
$("#d1").click(function(){
                $("#d1").data('clicked', true);
                // then call_server to get result  and append to div2
}
```

but it fails it always append the same result and i end up with big list of duplicates

Comment: Your click function will be called every time you click #d1. You have to remove it when you click it first time. Or check if it been click and do nothing in the function

Comment: how to check if it has been clicked and do nothing in the function

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple choices, but the general problem is once someone clicks on the div the event is still there and exists.

You could do this:

```
$("#d1").on('click', function(){
                // then call_server to get result  and append to div2
                $(this).off('click');

});
```

And remove the event once it has been clicked. OR

You could do this..

```
$("#d1").one('click', function(){
                $("#d1").data('clicked', true);
                // then call_server to get result  and append to div2

});
```

The .one() method will ensure the function is called only once, then the event is removed automatically.

Then once the user gets a notification of a new friend request you could reactivate the div with another .one() method.

Comment: `$(this).off();` without any args won't do anything `$(this).off('click');` would be correct and event binding should be done with `.on()` otherwise this won't work at all.

Comment: EDIT: Just read the jquery doc. and .off() without any parameters will actually "Remove all event handlers from " the targetted element.

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: still you can correct your closing tag of click event.

Comment: correct but its better to provide specific event to get `.off()` isn't it better practice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want your click event to be called only once.

```
$("#d1").click(function(){
    $("#d1").data('clicked', true);
     // then call_server to get result  and append to div2
     this.onclick = null; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be done this way:

```
$("#d1").click(function(){
    if($("#d1").data('clicked')) {              
       // do nothing  
       return;         
    } else {
       $("#d1").data('clicked', true);
       // then call_server to get result  and append to div2
    }
});
```

---

Still i would like to see how you are going to call your ajax i think you should post your ajax method at your question post. You can check if that is going to call next 10, 20...*(yourchoice of number)* records.

Comment: Exactly same as my answer.